Using hibernate to create first web application and hitting a wall getting table to show up in database
I have been working on my first application in Spring Boot using Hibernate to create sql for my Postgres Server and am absolutely stumped on what to do next to get my tables to show up correctly in my backend. I have toyed around quite a bit with my application properties file but with so many deprecated answers regarding hibernate and spring boot going back to before I was born I am not sure which ones ought to stay and which should go. Everything is in one package. Attached is my code.
application.properties
spring.application.name=Clowns
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=IPromiseThisIsRightIt'sJustAlsoMyComputerPasswordBcIDidn'tUnderstandWhatPostgresWasAskingFor

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.allow_jdbc_metadata_access=false
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.create_namespaces=true

ClownApplication.java

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.###.training.clowns")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.###.training.clowns")
public class ClownApplication {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClownApplication.class, args);
    }
}

ClownRepository.java

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ClownRepository extends JpaRepository<Clown, Long> {
    
}

Pom.xml


`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.###.training</groupId>
  <artifactId>clowns</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>clowns Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>clowns</finalName>
  </build>
</project>

Clown.java



import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table
public class Clown {


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "clown_sequence", 
        sequenceName = "clown_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1    
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator= "clown_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private Integer yrsofservice;
    private String name;
    private String skill;

    public Clown() {

    }

    public Clown(Integer yrsofservice, String name, String skill) {
        this.yrsofservice = yrsofservice;
        this.name = name;
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Clown(Long id, Integer yrsofservice, String name, String skill) {
        this.id = id;
        this.yrsofservice = yrsofservice;
        this.name = name;
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getYrsofservice() {
        return yrsofservice;
    }

    public void setYrsofservice(Integer yrsofservice) {
        this.yrsofservice = yrsofservice;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Clown [id=" + id + ", yrsofservice=" + yrsofservice + ", name=" + name + ", skill=" + skill + "]";
    }
    
}

ClownConfig.java


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class ClownConfig {
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner (
        ClownRepository repository ) {
        return args -> {
            Clown chuckles = new Clown(1L, 10, "Chuckles", "Juggling");
            Clown caesar = new Clown(2L, 10, "Caesar", "Magic");
            repository.saveAll(List.of(chuckles, caesar));
        };
    }   
}


ClownService.java


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ClownService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClownRepository clownRepository;


    public Clown findById(Long id) {
        return new Clown(1L, 10, "Chuckles", "Juggling");
    }

    public Clown newClown(Clown newClown) {
        return new Clown(1L, 10, "Chuckles", "Juggling");
    }

    public Clown replaceClown(Long id) {
        return new Clown(1L, 10, "Chuckles", "Juggling");

    }

    public ClownRepository getClownRepository() {
        return clownRepository;
    }

    public void setClownRepository(ClownRepository clownRepository) {
        this.clownRepository = clownRepository;
    }

    public List<Clown> all() {
        return clownRepository.findAll();

    }
    
}

Service is mostly untouched because I would like proof that I can actually make a table in the database before continuing in my work.
Output:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

2024-06-11T10:18:59.840-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] c.q.training.clowns.ClownApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-11T10:19:00.615-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-06-11T10:19:00.716-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 86 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-06-11T10:19:01.603-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-06-11T10:19:01.613-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-06-11T10:19:01.614-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
2024-06-11T10:19:01.755-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-06-11T10:19:01.757-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1819 ms
2024-06-11T10:19:01.963-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-06-11T10:19:02.031-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-06-11T10:19:02.079-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-06-11T10:19:02.389-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-06-11T10:19:02.411-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-06-11T10:19:02.703-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7e050be1
2024-06-11T10:19:02.705-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-06-11T10:19:03.706-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists clown cascade
Hibernate: 
    drop sequence if exists clown_sequence
Hibernate: 
    create sequence clown_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: 
    create table clown (
        yrsofservice integer,
        id bigint not null,
        name varchar(255),
        skill varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
2024-06-11T10:19:03.802-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-06-11T10:19:04.130-05:00  WARN 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-06-11T10:19:04.563-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-06-11T10:19:04.576-05:00  INFO 24928 --- [Clowns] [           main] c.q.training.clowns.ClownApplication     : Started ClownApplication in 5.195 seconds (process running for 5.851)

Again I have tried messing around in my properties file QUITE a bit to see if a lucky copy paste off stack overflow might fix my issue but let me know if anyone has any ideas or if you are able to replicate without issue. No errors occur when this code is run, Tomcat server apparently starts without issue, just no evidence of anything on back end. Thanks

@ValerijDobler I am not sure what you mean by update but I have been refreshing in pgAdmin after each attempt to run.

When are you checking your schema? spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop leads to create the schema on startup and drops everything after server stops. Did you also check the several schemas in pgadmin?

@Raphi1 I have only one schema in pgadmin named public that I was hoping to just place my clowns table into. Not sure what is meant by checking my schema, sorry I am quite new to this!

The schema is being dropped when you stop the appilcation. So you have to check the schema in pgadmin while your application is running.

@Ralphi1 I am checking during the running of the application, but nothing appears in tables under the only schema in the database.

@Ralphi1 From what I understand I should use create-drop until I have successfully created my table and then update afterwards, but let me know if I have understood that incorrectly

Try to create a database manually in pgadmin and then add it in your connection string spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<my-database> in application.properties. If you already have a database (probably called postgres) add it to the connection string

@Raphi1 You are a genius and I love you. I wasn't specifying the specific database because it was the only one I had connected to in pgAdmin but apparently that's a necessity. <3.
